# call $emit event from angular to angularJS (publish-subscribe pattern)

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-hybrid

I have a hybrid angular application tha uses both angularJS and angular 5.

I'm migrating a controller from angularJS to angular 5. This controller (let's call controller1) have the following code:

```
$rootScope.$emit('goToHomeEvent', 'Navigate to HomePage');
```

Then, I have another controller (let's call controller2) that subscribes the `goToHomeEvent`:

```
 $rootScope.$on('goToHomeEvent', function (event, data) {
            //Do some stuff
        });
```

My goal is to only migrate the controller1 to angular 5, mantaining the code of controller2 has it is, maintaining the ability to subscribe the `goToHomeEvent` event.

Any suggestions?

Comment: write a service with a method that emit an event an subscribe to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I came up is to create global functions and associate them to them to the window variable like this:

controller1:

```
$rootScope.$emit('goToHomeEvent', 'Navigate to HomePage');
window.goToHomeEvent(data);
```

controller2 (in angular 2+):

```
window["goToHomeEvent"] = fuction(data) {
    //do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that you could probably make usage of the localStorage for this as they dont't really communicate between each other.

I would suggest you to populate the localStorage on emit and watch it in the controller2. It's probably going to work although I don't know if it's the best approach for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Our solution was a variation on the global.  In the angularJS file at top level that calls `.module('app').run(fn)`, we inject the `$rootScope`, `$q`, `$injector`, and `$state` and set them to a global var `app` (as opposed to directly onto the window object).  So Angular2+ calls `app.$rootscope.`etc.

`app.$q` is effectively the browser's native/polyfilled `Promise.resolve` and related functions, so $q's replacement doesn't need to be injected into newer code.

`app.$state` is just for router concerns. Once you change over to Angular2's router, re-implement the parts of $state that you actually use in terms of the new router.

`app.$injector` is useful for a lot of oddball situations.

Answer (score 0):

i've solved by global function without emit/broadcast:

AngularJS:

```
$window.bridgeFormAngular = function (params)
  {
    console.log(params);
  }
```

Angular 7:

```
public sendToAngularJS(params: Object)
  {
    window["bridgeFormAngular"](params);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade the $rootscope of angularjs and use it inside the Angular side of the hybrid.
You will have to follow the following steps:
1 - Register the '$rootScope' service as a provider inside Angular:

```js
@NgModule({
  providers: [{
    provide: '$rootScope',
    useFactory: ($injector: any) => $injector.get('$rootScope'),
    deps: ['$injector']
  }]
})
```

2 - Use the $rootScope inside your Angular components or Services via injection:

constructor(@Inject('$rootScope') private _rootScope: any) {}

```js
constructor(@Inject('$rootScope') private _rootScope: any) {}
```